# How will this code work?

Tags: c++

Suppose we are creating two objects of class `Base`:

```
Base *b1 = new Base();
Base *b2 = new Base();
```

after that I did like:

```
*b1 = *b2;
```

then, what will happen?

As per my understanding:

assignment operator will be used in that case - default one generated by compiler or provided by "Base" class designer. Constructor is supposed to "construct" object and in presented scenario both objects - pointed by b1 and b2 - are already created.

Comment: hims, looking at your history of *answering* C++ questions about pointers and inheritance, I think you can put forward a draft answer.  Maybe then we could verify your answer is correct, or help you if you are confused.

Comment: @Nicholas: I have modified that. have a look above.

Comment: @Maroun: if you have any update on this. Pls see the above question: I have addressed my reply along with question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Base` object referred by `p2` will be copyed into the one referred by `p1`, unless another implmenmetation for `Base::operator=` is given.